# DEEP LINKS for "Cordova android" : It only redirects to appstore page from weblink, But not opening internal pages on installed app

Tags: cordova, phonegap, cordova-android

I have tried many tutorials but not able to make it working. Some tutorials are confusing as they provide details for both ios and android.
I have followed https://github.com/e-imaxina/cordova-plugin-deeplinks 
I have installed plugin cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-deeplinks
Next is made changes in config.xml file.

```
  <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleInstance" />  
 <universal-links>
    <host name="mydomainname.com" />    <path url="/somepage/" />    </universal-links>
```

added on page on domain and added given code :

```
<link rel="alternate"> href="androidapp://com.XXXXXX.XXXXX/http/mydomainname.com/somepage/"> />
```

also provide one hyperlink.

On paystore I have verifies domain. When we click on webpage it only redirects to appstore page. But not opening internal pages on installed app.

Answer (score 0):

Have you allowed navigation for your domain in your config.?

```
<allow-navigation href="http://yourdomainname.com/*" />
```

Comment: Yes, in your config.xml file.